# Extract raw text/data from a Google Sheet to a HTML Webpage

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-sheets

I have a basic website in which I intend to fill with a large amount of informative text. I wish to separate the content from the actual source code I use so my code is more efficient and organised. How do I go about doing this?

I tried publishing my Google sheet and using the code:

```
<div class="content_text">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Th2gcOG92xex39mE_Ql0cYqN3I6BFPPQ-KQRUk-z48I/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

However this left me with:

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate the formatting to leave me with just the raw text?

Comment: By "eliminate the formatting to leave me with just the raw text" you mean you don't want the header and footer, and also the grid lines removed? too look like this? [Image Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gRQl1.png)

Comment: Yes, I want it to look like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few undocumented parameters, you just need to modify the URL in the code adding the parameter `chrome=false` removes the title bar and `gridlines=false` will remove the borders. Your URL should look like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1Th2gcOG92xex39mE_Ql0cYqN3I6BFPPQ-KQRUk-z48I/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&chrome=false&gridlines=false
```

Just replace the URL in the `src` attribute of your `iframe` tag.

Comment: Is there a way for me to format the data, such as change the font-size and font-family using CSS coding? Out of the following:
border: none;
width: inherit;
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: inherit;
: only the first two styling commands were successful; I'm trying to achieve the last two for aesthetics in my webpage.

Comment: There are two things, the style of the iframe and the style of the page embedded in the iframe. You can set the style of the iframe block the usual way, with `css` or the `html style attribute`. On the other hand,  content of the iframe is not completely under your control, but you can try manipulate it with javascript but it might not work with `cross domain`